# How do I make CheckBox in ASP.NET MVC 4 (Edit Version)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want make Type input Checkbox in my Edit View,

this for my Model

```
public partial class iseng
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string hobi1 { get; set; }
    public string hobi2 { get; set; }
    public string hobi3 { get; set; }
}
```

and this for my Razor View

```
<label>Hobi:</label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.iseng.hobi1, "Makan")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.iseng.hobi2, "Minum")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.iseng.hobi3, "Tidur")
```

How do I Fix it?

Comment: `CheckBoxFor()` is for binding to a `bool`, not a `string`

Comment: soo, I just change string to bool ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes, and then its `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.hobi1)` - you 2nd parameter makes no sense - that adds html attributes and would result in `length="5"`

Comment: can you write in code please, @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Remember)
```

Will generate:

```
<input id="Remember" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Remember" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Remember" />
```

How does it work:

If checkbox not checked, form submit only hidden (false)
If checked, then form submit two fields (false and true) and MVC set true for bool property

```
  <input id="Remember" name="Remember" type="checkbox 
  value="@Model.Remember"/>
```

This will always send default value, if checked

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this one

public partial class iseng
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool hobi1 { get; set; }
    public bool hobi2 { get; set; }
    public bool hobi3 { get; set; }
}

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.hobi1, "Makan")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.hobi2, "Minum")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.hobi3, "Tidur")

or use like this

@Html.CheckBox("id", true)
```